# Use a lookup table in a data frame to standardize data in a nested list

Tags: r, lookup

Hi I have a lot of hydrological data on streamflow(Q) that I need to standardize. I have a large nested table with a layout like the one below that I need to keep:

```
Flowtestlist <- list(list("910" = data.frame( Q=c(650, 720, 550, 580, 800)),
            "950" = data.frame( Q=c(550, 770, 520, 540, 790))),
            list ("910" = data.frame( Q=c(450, 620, 750, 580, 800)),
             "950" = data.frame( Q=c(650, 750, 580, 520, 890))))
```

In the list above I have levels [[1]] and [[2]], in reality I have 9 of them and those are also model numbers. Within each model I have 18 subbasins numbered 910, 950 etc (in the example above just two subbasins 910, 950 for simplicity). The subbasins contain data on streamflow (Q).

I also have a lookup table:

```
test_model <- c(1,1,2,2)
test_subbasin <- c(910,950,910,950)
Q_mean <- c(870,765,823,689)
FlowtestDF <- data.frame(test_model, test_subbasin, Q_mean)
```

This data frame consists of data with the reference period streamflow means (Q_mean) for each model and subbasin. This is my lookup table.
I want to take each Q from the nested table and find the matching model number and subbasin in the lookup table and divide it to get the standardized streamflow Q_st.

```
fun_st <- function(x, y=FlowtestDF) { x$Q_st <- x$Q/y$Q_mean
                          x <- x}

testresult  <- lapply( Flowtestlist, lapply, fun_st)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. As I understand the function can't find the appropriate location of the needed number in the lookup table (model and subbasin). How can I fix this?

Comment: Your life will become much easier if you dispense with "that I need to keep". If this data structure is needed for a specific task, you can always recreate it. But I would first transform the data into a "tidy" data.frame. That allows use of efficient standard approaches.

Answer (score 0):

### Hi, i understand that you want to keep the original structure of the data,

however it is not clear where the new values for the standardized streamflow *Q_st* will fit inside.

From a programmatical standpoint, what you are trying to do here; using listapply with a lookuptable over a list of unnamed sublists of one dimensional dataframes (all identical named and all columns named "Q") - is very tricky ( at least for me)

I would rather save myself from this headache and, as Roland suggested, do it in a tidy fashion.

There are a lot of solutions to this;
This is how I would do it:

```
library(purrr);library(tidyr);library(dplyr)
```

### 1. Reconstruct

```
Flowtest_df<-map_df(Flowtestlist, ~.x, .id = "test_model") %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3, names_to = "test_subbasin")
```

### convert the lookuptables columns to character to join tables

```
FlowtestDF$test_model<-as.character(FlowtestDF$test_model)
FlowtestDF$test_subbasin<-as.character(FlowtestDF$test_subbasin)
```

can be skipped if you assign it as characters

### 2. join them

```
Flowtest_df %>% left_join(FlowtestDF) %>%
  mutate(Q_st=value$Q/Q_mean) # 3. do the calculation
```

This will give you this kind of output that is much cleaner to read for machine aswell as us mortals.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  test_model test_subbasin value$Q Q_mean  Q_st
  <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 1          910               650    870 0.747
2 1          950               550    765 0.719
3 1          910               720    870 0.828
```

Comment: Sorry but running the code in the first stage suggested by you results in Error: Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames.

Comment: strange it works fine with my installation. whats your packageVersion("purrr") output?

Comment: it's 0.3.4. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: idk the code works fien on my side  i have purrr 0.3.4, R version 4.1.0, dplyr '1.0.7’, tidyr ‘1.1.3’.

Comment: I updated various packages and now it works. I run the code you advised on my actual code and data and I obtained results. But now I have an issue with returning to the original nested data structure. I'm trying to do it with functions nest or list but it's not working. Could you advise what function would be best to nest it again?